# Mysqli table sorting with the thead?

Tags: php, sorting, mysqli

Okay so i have managed to implement Sorting when you click the link of the thead. But if i want to change the asc to desc i have to change the code,
is there any way using PHP where i can sort the table as descending if its showing as asc?

eg pseudo:
If current column is asc then sort desc?

Here is my current code:

```
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
    $sorting = $_GET['sort'];
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM routes ORDER BY $sorting DESC");
}
```

This is my link structure:

Route ID

To confirm when the user clicks on the link it will sort and if they click the same link again it will sort opposite way.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the array, so if they are firstly sorted asc will become desc:

```
array array_reverse ( array $array [, bool $preserve_keys = false ] )
```

In order to achieve this:

```
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
    $sorting = $_GET['sort'];
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM routes ORDER BY $sorting DESC"); }
```

1.- Convert your mysql result resource to an array:

```
$routes = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $routes[] = $row;
}
```

2.- Reverse the resulting array

```
  $routes_asc = array_reverse($routes);
```

Comment: Im new php kindy please explain how to implement an array like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the last sort type in sessions.

```
if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {
    $sorting = $_GET['sort'];

    // check the last sort type used
    $sort = ($_SESSION['last_sort_type'] == 'DESC') ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM routes ORDER BY $sorting $sort");

    // store it in session.
    $_SESSION['last_sort_type'] = $sort;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If i use sessions do i need to define the session somewhere? Because when i tested this out it was saying undefined session

Comment: You would have to do this at the start of your script - `if(session_id()==''){session_start();}`